# How to make fuzzy rules?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I have a dataset with weather factors(rainfall, humidity, temperature etc.) and crop yield. I want to make fuzzy rules. Considering the large number of features, it cannot be done manually by observing patterns.

Are there any methods to make fuzzy rules? (Without doing it manually)

Comment: The data can be clustered with Fuzzy regression. It will analyze and visualize the relationship between different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it depends on what kind of data you want to approximate.

- For text or strings try using regular expressions - there should be a library in just about all languages.
- For numerical data, try using a mixture of boolean with equality statements, along with a delta: eg is (x => y), (x == y+d)